# Ubuntu 15.04 gets stuck on boot

Tags: boot, cuda

When I start my laptop today, I just get stuck in this page.

[image: screenshot]

I can't open terminal by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, or tty1 by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. (Those are methods I found online) And restart does not work, either.

The only reason I can come up with is that I installed cuda driver software yesterday.

What am I supposed to do, please? Because I really don't want to reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: Your photo is really hard to read. Could you try to make a better one with less blur, please?

Comment: And in the GRUB boot menu (if it does not show up, hold SHIFT while booting, before Ubuntu starts to load), please try to boot "Advanced Options" > "Ubuntu, with Linux %kernel version% (recovery mode)". Then try the options "resume" which will boot normally, but with different kernel options, if it fails, try "failsafeX" which boots on minimal graphics, else try "root", which boots to a root terminal. For the last, follow https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode. Then report back here which options worked and somebody can continue to figure out a permanent fix.